# How to use a variable when grabbing data in vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to make a method of mine dynamic, what I'm trying to do is pass a string to a method and then that method will adjust my data accordingly.

So when I pass over the poster's role it should then pass it to `this.post.${user}.name`.
`this.post.${user}.name` would then "display" as `this.post.admin.name` and then grab the admin's name.

Hope that made sense.

Here is my code

```
<template>
    <div>
        <table class="table table-borderless table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Posters</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ getName('admin') }}</td>
                </tr>
                    <td>{{ getName('poster') }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['post'],
        data() {
            return {
              
            }
        },
        methods: {
            getName(user){
                if(this.post.${user}.name === null)
                {
                    return "Unknown";
                }else{
                    return this.post.${user}.name;
                }
            }  
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation) with the dynamic property name:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    getName(user) {
      if(!this.post[user]?.name) {
        return "Unknown";
      } else {
        return this.post[user].name;
      }

      // OR:
      return this.post[user]?.name ?? "Unknown";
    }
  }
}
```